# Email address verification with php issue on webserver

Tags: php, telnet, email-validation

I am trying to verify email with PHP script but I am getting some strange errors.

My script is working fine on localhost but when I upload the script to the web server it's not working, even if every email address I test with is showing correct.

When I look at the connecting log, I see find that doesn't look right. Like when I connect with telnet and type the bellow command

```
mail from: <postmaster@mydomain.com>
```

I get this response

```
250 2.1.0 OK ed10si5453372wjb.149 - gsmtp

rcpt to: <abc12765tyus@gmail.com>
```

I got this response

```
550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
```

, however when I use my script, with the same command

```
MAIL FROM: <postmaster@mydomain.com>
```

I receive this:

```
220 and/or bulk e-mail.

rcpt to: <abc12765tyus@gmail.com>
```

I got this response

```
250 srv.mydomain.com Hello srv.mydomain.com [192.*.*.*]
```

What can be issue and how to solve this?

Comment: Please, add the related portion of your script.

Comment: Hello @Rael Gugelmin Cunha i am using same code as https://github.com/zytzagoo/smtp-validate-email/blob/master/smtp-validate-email.php but its not working on Live Web server (VPS)